# How to read attendance details from essl finger tips through PHP?

Tags: php, fingerprint

We are using eSSL fingertips machine to manage employee attendance system. Now i want to read data (IN and Out time) from this machine through PHP code.

How can i do this?

Comment: You have to use zk sdk downloaded from https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory.html. This helps to communicate the device with TCP/IP. For http communication, check http://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html

Answer (score -1):

While installing Select the favorable database for the php or other Scripting languages. use the Connection script to connect to database in Other Scripting languages. Study the structure of the database and retrieve the code from the database.

If your are using MSSQL as Database.
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP,

Connection string for MSSQL-PHP
php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

If your are using oracle as Database.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php

Duplicate Question : stackoverflow.com/questions/25017188/essl-finger-print-u990-how-to-retrieve-the-data-through-any-language/37675408#37675408